# functional programming with scala

Tags: scala, recursion

I've been trying to enhance my knowledge with scala. 
I am trying to implement this function recursively but having difficulty.

[image]

My main question IS, how can you accept a list in the parameter that accepts either a list or numbers.

Comment: `List[Any]` would go.

Comment: This is what I have so far but it is not working.

def depth(l: List[Any]) : Int = {
   for (i <- l){
    i match {
     case list: List[Any] => 1 + depth(list)
    }
   }

Comment: And that would not be. `for (i <- l) {}` gives you `Unit` and not `Int` as you intended. To take results out from `for` expression you need to `yield` them

Comment: Im so confused @ayvango

Comment: `for {x <- collection} f(x)` is syntax sugar for the `foreach` function in http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/nightly/docs/library/index.html#scala.collection.GenTraversableLike . Its signature is `def foreach[U](f: (A) ⇒ U): Unit`. So it returns `Unit` but you need to get `Int` somehow

Answer (score 3):

`depth(x: Any): Int` is the signature you want, then pattern match on `x` to determine if it's a `List[_]` or not, where `_` indicates you don't care what's in the list. (Using `Seq[_]` would be the more idiomatic Scala type to use, actually.) Note that the example shown is missing a pair of parens, `List(1, 2, List(3))...` It also assumes that `depth(8) == 0` (for example).

A tricky part is that you shouldn't assume that a nested list will either be the first or last element in the "parent" list, i.e., `...List(1,List(2,3),4)...` is possible.

A final bit worth mentioning; if you were building a "production" `depth` method, it would be worth having a `Tree` abstraction with `Node` and `Leaf` concrete types so you can use a better type signature, `depth(tree: Tree[_]): Int`, to make it explicitly clear when something represents part of the tree structure vs. data in the tree. Using `List` here is convenient for the exercise, but a bit ambiguous otherwise, since you could have a tree of stuff where some nodes are actually lists.

Comment: oh, yes. Kill him with catamorphism abstraction

Answer (score 1):

I will try to answer this by giving a shot on the recursive solution:

```
def depth(listOrNum: Any): Int = {
  def help(y: Any, c: Int): Int = {
    y match {
      case y: Int => c
      case List(curHead, rest @ _*) =>
        Math.max(help(curHead, c+1), help(rest, c))
      case _ => 0
    }
  }
  help(listOrNum, 0)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`collect` is handy here:

```
def depth(xs: List[Any]): Int =
  1 + xs.collect{case xs: List[_] => depth(xs)}
        .foldLeft(0)(_ max _)
```

P.S. I agree with Dean's comments about the type `List[Any]` being a poor way to represent trees. `List[Any]` is a type that should never appear in ordinary Scala code, so I'm sad to see it used in an exercise intended for beginners.

Answer (score 0):

If you are insisting on using for comprehension, I can provide implementation that works with it.

First you define two useful classes

```
import scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom
import scala.collection.mutable.Builder

class Folder[T](init : T, step : (T,T) => T) extends Builder[T,T] {
  private[this] var state = init
  override def += (elem : T) = {
    state = step(state, elem)
    this
  }
  override def clear() {
    state = init
  }
  override def result() : T = state
}

class CanBuildFolder[F,T](init : T, step : (T,T) => T) extends CanBuildFrom[F,T,T] {
  override def apply() : Builder[T,T] = new Folder(init, step)
  override def apply(from : F) : Builder[T,T] = new Folder(init, step)
}
```

than you can use them with the for comprehension

```
import scala.math.max

object Test {
  val example = List(1, List(2, 3), List( List(4, 5), 6, List(7, List(List(8), 9))))
  implicit val maxFolder = new CanBuildFolder[List[Any], Int](0, max)

  def depth(source : List[Any]) : Int =
    for (x <- source) yield x match {
      case l : List[Any] => depth(l) + 1
      case _ => 1
    }

  assert(depth(example) == 5)
}
```